# What is the purpose of a pre-trained network in Faster R-CNN?

Tags: faster-rcnn, conv-neural-network

I am not able to understand the purpose of a pre-trained network. From what I read, it is used for the RPN and the Classification Network. But I dont't understand how.

Comment: Not an expert. I just scimmed through the Faster R-CNN paper and it looks like an architecture. Think about it like `f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 +cx + d` and `f(x) = 5x^3 - 3x^2 + 2`. There `f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 +cx + d` is the architecture and `f(x) = 5x^3 - 3x^2 + 2` a model with set weights (a = 5, b = -3, c = 0, d = 2). So the pre-trained Faster R-CNN network has, hence the name, been trained on a bunch of data and now the weights are available to you to continue training, but on your data.

Answer (score 0):

CNNs take a notoriously long time to train, especially for more complex models with higher resolutions. In order to avoid the days of training on a high-end GPU, pre-trained models have been made available. You then just have to train on your specific data (assuming your data is similar to the pre-trained data). For instance, if you want to train a CNN to recognize cats in high resolution images, you might want to start with a pre-trained model that recognizes dogs. The training should take a lot, lot less time due to the fact that a lot of the same underlying patterns have already been learned and all your training needs to do is differentiate cats from dogs.